# RavenDB Sql Replication and Postgres uuid

Tags: postgresql, ravendb, uuid, guid, npgsql

I have set up Sql Replication using Postgres/Npgsql.

We are using Guids for ids in Ravendb.
Everything is working fine as long as my id column in Postgres is of type `varchar`, but if I set it to `uuid`, which should be the correct type to match `Guid`, it fails.

It also fails for other columns than id.

Postgres log gives me:

> operator does not exist: uuid = text at character 34
>   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Postgres schema looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.materiels
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  type character varying(50),
  nummer integer,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT materiels_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Replacing first line with

```
id character varying(50) NOT NULL
```

will make it work.

My replication setup looks like this:

[image: Replication setup]
If I set the replication up to use MSSql it works using MSSql's `uniqueidentifier` data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare `UUID` with `TEXT`, then you need to create operators for that. The one solving your error would look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION uuid_equal_text(uuid, text) 
 RETURNS boolean 
 LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE 
AS 
$body$ 
   SELECT $1 = $2::uuid 
$body$;

CREATE OPERATOR =(
  PROCEDURE = uuid_equal_text,
  LEFTARG = uuid,
  RIGHTARG = text);
```

EDIT: Alternate solution suggested by author of this question himself:

```
CREATE CAST (text AS uuid)
WITH INOUT
AS IMPLICIT;
```

Comment: Wow thats a great solution. Works like a charm. Keep being amazed at how powerfull Postgres is!

Comment: Is there a way of doing this for casting from text to uuid as well?
This solution fixed the "DELETE ...WHERE " part of the replication. Now the INSERT part fails.

Comment: Found CREATE CAST, which seems to be able to do the trick. Cant quite make it work though.
Will look more into it later

Comment: You are right, this can be done also by creating cast. `CREATE CAST (text AS uuid) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;`. Keep in mind tho, this seem to work only for `=` operator. It will work for `INSERT`.

Comment: Actually CAST works with any operators. Seems like I had some unfinished operators left from my testing and they didn't show up in pgAdmin.

Comment: YEAH! It seems to be working. I was trying with CAST (varchar AS uuid), but it need to be CAST (text AS uuid).
Need to test a bit more, but at first glance replication seems to work perfectly now.
Thanks a bunch